# Jumbotron Div Background video

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have been looking loads for a code that works but havent been lucky so far. I want to insert a video in the jumbotron of the website im making.

I have this div in HTML:

```
<div class="center jumbotron">

            <h1 class="txtjumbo">We are engage ME!</h1>
            <p class="txtjumbo">We are results driven.</p>
            <p><a class="btn center btn-primary btn-lg" id="botjumbo" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
```

And this is how my website looks and where I want the video. Ideally the background video would be 100% of window size, but could achieve this and I tried 500 CSS codes!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A big thing to remember is the `z-index` rule, specifically the behavior of `z-index: -1`, which puts an item behind everything else.

My version, expanded and modified from AnthyG's codepen is below (much fuller example at http://codepen.io/kenbellows/pen/ZWmgRB). I also set the video to `position: fixed`, mostly for personal aesthetic preference, but it would work the same with `position: absolute`.

```css
#bg-video {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
}

.jumbovidtext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
}

.jumbotron {
  background: rgba(128,128,128,0.5);
  margin: 25vh 0;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

main {
  /* Give the main content container a solid background color to hide the fixed position video */
  background: #fff;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" class="img-responsive pull-left" id="brand-img" src="https://placehold.it/32x32" />
        My Company
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <video id="bg-video" autoplay="true" loop="loop" preload="metadata" muted="muted">
    <source src="http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/big_buck_bunny_480p_stereo.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  </video>
  
  <div class="center jumbovidtext text-center">
    <h1 class="txtjumbo">We are engage ME!</h1>
    <p class="txtjumbo">We are results driven.</p>
    <p><a class="btn center btn-primary btn-lg" id="botjumbo" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- primary content here -->
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Kuddos for putting Big Buck Bunny movie :D

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <video id="bg-video" autoplay="true" loop="loop" preload="metadata" muted="muted">
        <source src="/PATH/TO/VIDEOFILE" type="video/TYPE" />
    </video>
    <div class="center jumbovidtext">
        <h1 class="txtjumbo">We are engage ME!</h1>
        <p class="txtjumbo">We are results driven.</p>
        <p><a class="btn center btn-primary btn-lg" id="botjumbo" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#bg-video {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
.jumbovidtext {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Here's'a link to the thingy on codepen: http://codepen.io/anthyG/pen/NNEbyg

Comment: One suggestion: expand the .jumbovidtext class to cover the whole video
http://codepen.io/kenbellows/pen/ZWmgRB